# Hive query optimization for aggregated columns appear once in a select statement

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

if there are multi aggregated column in one select, would the be evaluated only once? for example:

```
select
    date,
    count(userid) as uv,
    sum(isclick) as clickcnt,
    count(userid) / sum(isclick) as ctr
from
    user_access_log
group by
    1
```

here both `count(userid)` and `sum(isclick)`  are used twice, would they be evaluated twice or only once, will hive do any query optimization?

Comment: explain plan with second reference and without and compare plans. Most probably it will be evaluated on the same reducer. You check

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

It doesn't make a difference.  The expense of running an aggregation query is almost entirely in bringing the rows for groups together.  For the most part, the aggregations themselves are not expensive.

The one exception is `count(distinct)` (well, `distinct` with any form).  This requires a bunch more overhead.

If you really want to run the aggregations only once, you can use a subquery:

```
select ual.*, (uv / clickcnt) as ctr
from (select date, count(userid) as uv, sum(isclick) as clickcnt,
      from user_access_log
      group by 1
     ) ual;
```

To be honest, I suspect that you actually want `count(distinct userid)`, so this might give a small improvement in performance.

Comment: This does not answer the question "will hive do any query optimization?"

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz . . . The question is irrelevant, especially because I think the OP's query is malformed.

Comment: And yet you are suggesting a rewrite  ("If you really want to run the aggregations only once, you can use a subquery") that intends to solve an issue that might not exists, potentially creating another issue (Do you know for sure that Hive supports view unfolding?).